# How to display content based on post author?

Tags: wordpress, if-statement, theming, author

I know that Jetpack's 'widget visibility' option can be used to display widgets on specific author pages. I would like to be able to do this in my theme's template file.

The list of conditional tags has options to see if one is on a specific author's archive page but not, seemingly, to check who the specific author of a post is.

This is basically what I want to do:

> If author is Mr. Incredible, show some html. If author is Mrs.
>   Incredible, show different html.

Is this possible? I imagine it should be but I haven't been able to find any how to on it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Sure! Your problem statement is a great start. Let's translate it into actual code:

> If author is Mr. Incredible, show some html. If author is Mrs. Incredible, show different html.

Becomes:

```
if ( is_author('Mr. Incredible Nickname or ID') ) {
    // echo some HTML
} elseif ( is_author('Mrs. Incredible Nickname or ID') ) {
    // echo different HTML
} else {
    // if neither, echo something else
}
```

The code should be readable, just like the problem statement.

You can read more about [is_author()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_author) [in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_author).

Additionally, if you need to check the author of individual posts, you can use [get_the_author()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author).

Comment: Thanks for the 'translation' - that looks to be exactly what I'm looking for as I can do it for all authors on the site in one go. Do you recommend just putting the php into single.php or calling a template file like Fatih Sari suggested above?

Comment: That's really up to you. Personally, I don't see a problem sticking  it directly into your **single.php**, or whatever file is running it

Comment: I'll see what works best - I'm using a premium theme and it using a lot of custom functions.

Comment: Great, please close up this question by selecting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can get post author ID.
2. With use it, get author nickname or [etc](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author_meta)...
3. And check your want with this.

Tip for you:

**in single.php**

```
<?php
   $ID = $post->post_author;
   $nickname = get_the_author_meta('nickname', $ID);
   if($nickname == "fors")
      include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/fors-template.php');
   else
      include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-default.php');
?>
```